# Which one of the following is better?

Tags: performance, haskell, parallel-processing

So I have two implementations of the function tabulate, which, given a function `f :: Int -> a` and a number `n`, should produce the list `[f 0, f 1, ..., f (n-1)]`. I'm trying to guess which one is better in terms of work and span.

```hs
tabulate1 :: (Int -> a) -> Int -> [a]
tabulate1 f n = tab (\x -> f (n - x)) n where
    tab _ 0 = []
    tab g n = let (x,xs) = (g n) ||| (tab g (n-1))
              in (x:xs)
```

```hs
tabulate2 :: (Int -> a) -> Int -> [a]
tabulate2 f n = tab f 0 (n-1) where
    tab f n m
        | n > m = []
        | n == m = [f n]
        | otherwise = let i = (n + m) `div` 2
                          (l, r) = (tab f n i) ||| (tab f i+1 m)
                      in (l ++ r)
```

While the first one avoids the using of `(++)`, which has linear work and span, the second one computes the two sublists in parallel but uses `(++)`.

So... which one is better?

Comment: How would you measure "better"?

Comment: Code reviews should go to the code review stack exchange.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen with better I mean the one that has lower costs in terms of work (one porcessor) and span (infinte processors), the least number of operations

Answer (score 2):

Time and space complexity in Haskell is often non-trivial as it is a lazy language. This means that while a function might be `O(n!)`, its result might never be needed and therefore never evaluated. Or like in this case, if your function returns a list, and only the first 3 elements are needed by other functions, only those are evaluated.

Anyways, your functions is just a particular case of `map`, and as such it could be coded in a much more readable way:

```
tabulate f n = map f [0..n]
```

Map is implemented with a fold, and is probably the most optimised version you could get

Comment: I think this answer misses the point that OP is trying to explicitly parallelize the invocations of `f`.

Comment: @moonGoose yeah I know this doesn't fully answer the question but I was trying to raise the issue / point of view of lazy evaluation